# AMP: Is it possible to always show the notification using amp-user-notification?

Tags: php, wordpress, amp-html

I did implement the `amp-user-notification`, I´d created an endpoint to be called to always show the notification. But if the user clicks on dismiss, it never shows again, only if I clear local storage. My implementation:

```
<style amp-custom>
  :root {
    --space-2: 1rem;   /* 16px */
  }
  amp-user-notification {
    top: 132px;
    bottom: inherit;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    amp-user-notification {
      top: 90px;    
    }
  }

  /* Center the notification content */
  amp-user-notification.sample-notification {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
  }
  amp-user-notification.sample-notification > button {
    padding: 4px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #303030;  
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    border-radius: 18px;
  }
  amp-user-notification > p > span {
    display: inline;
    color: rgb(13, 84, 162);
    font-weight: 600;
  }
</style>

<amp-user-notification
  data-show-if-href="https://my-web-site.com.br/dismissable.php"  
  id="my-notification"
  class="sample-notification">
    <p><span>CAROS CLIENTES</span>, entendemos a necessidade do isolamento em virtude da COVID-19. Como trabalhamos com um produto essencial, informamos que estamos <span>operando normalmente</span>. Para que você permaneça em casa seguro.
    </p>
    <button on="tap:my-notification.dismiss">&#10006;</button>
</amp-user-notification>
```

The URL on data-show-if-href always return:

```
{
    "showNotification": true
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Notification must always be on the page and cannot be closed?

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov It can be closed, but I want to show it every time the user come back to page.

Comment: Why use amp-user-notification at all in this case? A simple div which closes itself via <button on="tab:notification.close">Close</button>. Would achieve the same result without having to download an extra AMP extension.

Comment: @SebastianBenz sorry man, I didn´t get what you mean. I´m using this, because the AMP does not allow me to show a pop-up with the notification. If you know a better way, please show me the code.

Comment: Here is an example: https://jsbin.com/konetiweda/edit?html,output

Comment: @SebastianBenz thats cool, thanks, I´ll try it right now!